# Renault Megane 1.9 diesel convertible won't crank when I try to start it

Tags: starting, ignition, renault, megane

I have Renault Megane 2007 Diesel  convertible. Put card in, press start, lights come on, won't crank. Then says low battery. I put new battery on same thing. I tried a jump start still nothing. Can anyone help please ?

Comment: maybe it is a weak starter motor?

Comment: It sounds like you have a low battery. Whatever the story is with the 'new' battery, it simply sounds like you have low voltage.